# Facebook Graph API: The Remote Server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm intended to get facebook-insights from my company Page.
Reading FB documentation I have to create an FB-APP and with it "authenticated and obtained an access token, and then try some calls to access your account's ad campaign objects."
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/overview#gettingstarted)

The first part is concluded and my App asks privilegies to have the exteded permission do "ads_read" and generate me a Access Token.

But after that when I ASK some objetcs like Ad Account, Ad Campaign, etc I receive the message: "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

That's my code:

Default.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string facebook__client_id = "331449370396212";
    string urlBase = "https://tecnologia.chleba.net:94";

    string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + facebook__client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + urlBase + "/FacebookCallBack.aspx&scope=ads_read";
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

FacebookCallBack.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string facebook__client_id = "331449370396212";
    string facebook__client_secret = "";
    string urlBase = "";

    if (Request["code"] != null)
    {
        string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + facebook__client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + urlBase + "/FacebookCallBack.aspx&client_secret=" + facebook__client_secret + "&code=" + Request["code"].ToString();

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri(url));
        WebResponse res = (WebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
        url = sr.ReadToEnd();
        res.Close();
        string[] resposta = url.Split("&".ToCharArray());
        string token = resposta.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim().Replace("access_token=", string.Empty);

        // PROBLEM HERE

        string aUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/act_418011654925463?access_token="+ token;

        try
        {
            req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri(aUrl));
            res = (WebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
            string resultado = sr.ReadToEnd();
            res.Close();

            Response.Write(resultado);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("erro: "+ ex.Message + " - " + ex.InnerException);
        }

        Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is caused because your "**redirect_uri**" don't match. I was having a similar problem trying to get an access token.

If you change both of your

```
string urlBase
```

to

```
string urlBase = "https://tecnologia.chleba.net:94"
```

you should stop receiving error 400.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Man, the second one with string urlBase = "";  he doesn't use it in his code!